# Error reported in Google Cloud functions: message 'undefined' is not a valid object and no handlebars template has been provided instead

Tags: android, email, google-cloud-firestore, triggers, firebase-extensions

I'm trying to send an email from my Android Firebase app to an arbitrary email address using the Trigger Email extension. Following [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/official/firestore-send-email), I first set up the outbound mail service using sendGrid and tested it. Next, I created a Firestore documents collection named 'email' and set up some security rules for the collection. Finally, I installed the Trigger Email extension into my project and specified sender address, etc.

The code that adds email documents to the collection is as follows:

```
    private HashMap<String, String> emailMap = new HashMap<>();
                  .
                  .
                  .

    spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("to", emailaddr);
    emailMap.clear();
    emailMap.put("subject", getString(R.string.post_alert));
    emailMap.put("html", getString(R.string.posted_comment) + NL + NL + WEB_APP + url);
    data.put("message", emailMap);
    emailRef.add(data)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
                Toast.makeText(context, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                spinner.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

and, in fact, the document gets created and looks good:

[image]

However, the email never gets sent. Looking through the the Google Cloud functions logs, I see the following:

[image]

My question is, why is 'message' not a valid object? It looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I was having was due to two errors I made in configuring the Trigger email extension: the SMTP password was missing and I had the name of the email collection wrong.

I got past the problem I originally posted, now I've got a different one: the extension tried to send the email and updated the email document with an error:

[image]

Has anyone seen this error before?